# Proving $\{v, T(v)\}$ is linearly dependent $\iff T(v) = \pm v$ with $T \circ T = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$, with $T \circ T = I$

Prove $\{v, T(v)\}$ is linearly dependent $\iff T(v) = \pm v$

I am really stuck on this question.

I think $T(v) = \pm v \Rightarrow \{v, T(v)\}$ is linearly dependent, is fairly obvious, as
$T(v) = cv$ with $c = \pm 1$ (Is this valid?).

However I have no idea how to approach $\{v, T(v)\}$ is linearly dependent $\Rightarrow T(v) = \pm v$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work for the first direction is correct. For the other direction, notice that $T(v) = \lambda v$ since the set is linearly dependent, and since $T \circ T = I$, we get $v = \lambda T(v) = \lambda^2 v$, therefore $\lambda^2 - 1 = 0$ if $v \neq 0$, so $\lambda \in \{-1, 1\}$.